# Additional images in mailing using Mosaico

Tags: civimail, mosaico, images, header-footer

I have composed e-mail using Mosaico and everything looks fine.
But, when I sent the mailing, I see two missing image placeholders in head and in the footer. I cannot realize why. I did the investigation, and find out that there are some old images from the previous mailing. Have you any ideas, please?

[image: placeholderf of non existing images]

Comment: checking i understand. Am i right that you have reused an old mailing but when you edit it some old links to missing images show in the test even though you cannot see them in mosaico?

Comment: Yes, now I know, that many images from template repository was deleted. When I do Public view of any older mailing, there are also missing pictures. What happened? What can be the cause?

Comment: I can also confirm, that uploaded images to Mosaico are on the right place where they should be: wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/uploads

Comment: So the why they cannot be retrieved? Here is the path of missing image in the mailing: 

https://kontakty.eduin.cz/civicrm?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mosaico/img&src=https://kontakty.eduin.cz/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/uploads/super_u_itelka_1558057167f2036564c78370787a8244.jpg&method=resize&params=570,null

Comment: When I compose new template everything works, but I cannot reuse older template, where is broken image attachement.

Comment: if your images are now at a different path you can set up redirects so that they will still show from their old location

Comment: I can see the image here: https://kontakty.eduin.cz/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/uploads/super_u_itelka_1558057167f2036564c78370787a8244.jpg perhaps you have an issue with your Resource or Directly URLs or something else (civicrm.settings.php?) which is causing the path problem

Comment: I think there was an bug in some specific release. I have upgraded to civi 5.28.3 and latest Mosaico 2.5. Images are changing location without our intervention, we did not change any settings. Since today upgrade was also path changed, so the templates made yesterday has a problem today. I copied all images manually to both locations for now. The second location is wp-content/uploads/civicrm/... When I change the paths on mosaico configuration, all images in current location will be moved to the new one?